# make a histogram on android

Tags: android, image, histogram

I try to make a histogram image on android developmet, but i get a force close erorr on it.
this is my code to get the histogram value :

```
for (int i =0;i<width;++i){
            for(int j=0;j<height;++j){
                    pixel = bmp.getPixel(i,j);
                    r = Color.red(pixel);
                    g = Color.green(pixel);
                    b = Color.blue(pixel);
                    A = (int)((r+g+b)/3);
                    histogram[A]++;
            }
        }
```

if i embbeb the "histogram[A]++" code, the application get a force close erorr, but if the code deleted, the application run normaly...
any idea abaut it??

Comment: Can you post how your `histogram` variable is declared? Is it an `int[]` array with 256 elements?  Cause I think that's what it should be.

Comment: hahaha, i forgot to set the length of array like histogram[width*height]; XD

Comment: you should use getPixels() instead of getPixel. it will increase the performance dramatically. Sample code: `int[] pixels = new int[width * height]; src.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);` then get index depending on your for cycles and do `pixel = pixels[index];`